# All cells bold in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 table give me all cells with bold text, I need normal text in td's. Font-weight doesn't help/

```
<div class="row col-md-10 px-4 py-3 ">
   <table id="ServiceTable" class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Title</th>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4 btn-sm">Подробнее</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">date_isodate_set</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Thornton</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Hii</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

CSS:
#ServiceTable td {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

[image]

Head:

[image: sss111]

Whole css:

[image: sss]

Comment: At jsfiddle its working fine...

Comment: @FlavioCaruso  So what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: See if your css is linked right with the html file

Comment: @FlavioCaruso it is. I see it in view-source.

Comment: can you show the rest fo your css? maybe you are using bold on the same component

Comment: @FlavioCaruso see on top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192776/discussion-between-barmaxon-and-flavio-caruso).

Comment: estrange... can you open on an anonymous tab?

Comment: Try with hard refresh, maybe it is cached.

Comment: You are to post your code in text, not pictures.

Comment: @GrzegorzLasak tried that.

Comment: @Rob I did that, but stackoverflow told me to add more text where I really had nothing to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution. In my head tag I used link for google font. And there added font-weight parameter = 600 and only this weight:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600" rel="stylesheet">
```

So even when you try to change font-weight to this uploaded font, It won't work. It just needs to be customized:

[image]

Upload link would be like that:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
```